# How to create a "local" Gradle task?

Tags: gradle

I am new to Gradle.

Is there any way to make something similar to `local.properties` but for tasks? I wanna have a task that I am going to use only in my local environment for debugging purposes, but it should be ignored by the version control system. Is there any adequate way to do that?

I came up with an idea to create a `local.gradle` file and add `apply from: 'local.gradle'` to the `build.gradle`, and then adding `local.gradle` to `.gitignore`. It works on my local machine but fails on CI (because VCS knows nothing about `local.gradle`).

Thank you in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways to approach that:

1. Use [Initialization Scripts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#init_scripts). Those are per-user (i.e. local to the user, not the project) scripts that are executed before loading the actual gradle build script *or*
2. Add a small stub to your "real" `build.gradle` (or `build.gradle.kts` if you're using Kotlin) to load a local build file *if it's present*.:

   ```
   if (file("./local.gradle").exists()) {
     apply from: "./local.gradle"
   }
   ```

   Then add `local.gradle` to your `.gitignore` and it will be loaded when present, but ignored when it's missing.

Using Initialization scripts has the advantage that you don't need to do *anything* at all to your projects "real" files to use it, but might be an oversized hammer: those scripts will apply to **all** gradle builds you run, not just the ones of the current project.

Comment: The second option perfectly fits my case. Thank you very much!